# Extend the time of an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I have a function on the server to create hundreds of elements and store them in the database. This action takes time on the server and when the action finalize, it returns the result. The problem is that Ajax terminates the request after around 150000ms with Bad Request 400 and the runningProcess response.

The Ajax call is:

```
          showProgressCursor();
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: strUrl,
                data: {accountId: byId("account-id").value},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (oResult, strTextStatus, internalResponse) {
                    console.log("Success")
                    _showTheResult(oResult, strTextStatus, internalResponse, allDataError);
                    hideProgressCursor();
                },
                error: function(oResult) {
                    manageError(oResult);
                    console.log(oResult);
                    hideProgressCursor();
                }
            });
```

**Do you know how I can increase this time or cancel it until Ajax receives an answer?**

Extra: at the moment, I am showing a loading wheel but it would be better if I show a bar with the progress of the operation, could I show something like that? (I have thought of making a different recurring request (every second for example) and obtaining the total created and the total to be created and thus be able to have the progress. I don't know if this is a good solution)

Comment: *"The problem is that Ajax terminates the request after around 150000ms"* It's not "ajax" that's doing that, it's your server process. You can't solve this client-side. You need to update the server code/configuration.

Comment: As long as you're updating the server side of this, I suggest you split this API call into two parts: 1. An API call that starts the process and returns a unique identifier for it; 2. An API call that checks on the progress of the call that you send that unique identifier to. Having a pending network operation for two and a half minutes is problematic. :-)

Comment: Re your "extra": The way SO works, you need to ask just **one** question per question, not two or more. It's important for ensuring answers are on-topic and questions can be useful to others in the future.

Comment: [long polling vs websockets](https://www.google.com/search?q=long+polling+vs+websockets)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @T.J.Crowder I will take your advice and perform the operation in two phases. In the second phase I can show the process bar and so the users will know the status of the operation. I don't know if I can mark this as an answer to my question with your answer here.

Comment: The above are just comments, not *answers*, but I'm glad they helped! I suggest just removing the question. But if you prefer, I can post an answer containing the above. Either way, happy coding!

Comment: I think posting an answer may help other people with the same problem.